# How to use Camera presets list

Tags: camera

I have been exploring the camera settings in the object data tab and changed the camera by selecting (say) Galaxy S3 in the button marked camera presets. I am supposing that that changes the 'render camera' from its default to the focal length and sensor size of a Galaxy S3.

1. If that results in an equivalent focal length of 27mm do I need to do anything with that eg set the View lens in the properties panel to match it? It doesn't look like the latter impacts on the rendered view.
2. If I change the camera from default to S3 does this mean that if I map an photograph taken with a Galaxy S3 camera, that I have better chance of integrating it with objects I model?

But what is holding me up right now is

3. Once I have selected a particular camera in object data I cannot find a way back. I tried selecting Blender from the list of cameras but that retains the focal length of the S3 and maybe other parameters. How do I get back to default?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, the viewport lens only effects the viewport when you are not in camera mode.
2. Yes, that's the idea.
3. Add a new camera to the scene. Shift + A -> Camera. Delete the camera. Now, select your original camera and go to the Object Data tab and change the Camera Data to the new camera's data (which is the default).
   [image]